# Internal energy of compressed gas

Tags: energy

I've been reading about compressed air energy storage and keep coming across that in 300 bar containers the achievable energy is 0.1MJ/L. Is this 0.1MJ/L of the volume of the air it is compressed to or of the total L of air that was initially used? (E.g If 1500L is compressed to 300 bar into a 5L cylinder will the total energy be 0.5MJ or 150MJ)

Link - 
http://www.ijrmet.com/vol5issue1/2/11-SwadhinPatnaik.pdf

I have been trying to work this out but cannot seem to come up with the the 0.1MJ/L value.

Using the internal energy calculation U = 5/2PV I get 0.375MJ which is 0.00025MJ/L . (5L volume at 300 bar = 1500L total air. If I compress 1500L of air at 300 bar it can compress to 5L with total internal energy of 0.375MJ)

Using the equation in the wiki article
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_air_energy_storage

I get total of 0.7MJ for a 5L cylinder.

Could someone explain how they worked out the 0.1MJ/L value?
and
Do they consider total volume of air (1500L) or only the compressed air volume (5L) with the 0.1MJ/L value.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that the temperature of the gas inside the cylinder is high enough that the vibrational degree of freedom is important? If so, it should be $U=3PV$.

Comment: Never mind, your numbers force the compression to be isothermal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $PV=1\times 1500=300\times 5$ is constant, this implies the compression is isothermal, so the temperature of the gas does not change in this process. The internal energy an ideal gas is

$$U=c_VnT$$

where $c_V$ is the constant-volume molar heat capacity in units of J/(mol K). As such, since neither the number of particles nor the temperature of the gas changes during the compression, the total internal energy of the gas also does not change. So, using $c_V=20.8$ J/(mol K), $n=67$ mol (the amount of air in $1500$ L, and $T = 300$ K, we have that $U=418$ kJ. The energy density

$$u = \frac{U}{V} = \frac{c_VnT}{V}$$

in $5$ L of air is therefore $418/5=83.6$ kJ/L, which is pretty close to the value $0.1$ MJ/L given in the literature.

**However**, isothermal compression is typically really inefficient for large power outputs, according to the Wikipedia article in the question. Since the paper you reference is a design for a compressed-air-powered car, I suspect they use adiabatic compression instead, but that's impossible with the numbers you gave me. So I'll assume that you pulled those numbers out of thin air. In the adiabatic case, the temperature of the gas increases as you compress it, because you're no longer allowing it to cool during the compression. Therefore, the internal energy of the gas increases as well, so the energy density of the compressed gas should be higher in the adiabatic case. This is because the gas doesn't lose any energy to a thermal bath like in the isothermal case.